# why "sudo copa" command not working, while "copa" commands works

Tags: command-line, 22.04, sudo

I have installed homebrew with below instructions for ubuntu 22.04

https://owlhowto.com/how-to-install-homebrew-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Then I am able to install "copa" a Microsoft tool using command `brew install copa`

https://project-copacetic.github.io/copacetic/website/installation#development-setup

Now when I am trying to run the command `copa`, it's working

But when I tried with sudo `sudo copa`, then it giving below error

`sudo: copa: command not found`

What could the reason? why I am not able to run with sudo? Other commands like `sudo apt update` I am able to run.

`user1@Machine1:~$ whereis copa`

`copa: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/copa`

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498132/edit) to show us the complete output of `whereis copa`

Comment: @user535733, the output of `whereis copa`  = `copa: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/copa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, read [Why does Homebrew say sudo is bad? FAQ.](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad)

> tl;dr Sudo is dangerous, and you installed TextMate.app without sudo anyway.

> Homebrew refuses to work using sudo.

> You should only ever sudo a tool you trust. Of course, you can trust Homebrew  — but do you trust the multi-megabyte Makefile that Homebrew runs? Developers often understand C++ far better than they understand make syntax. It’s too high a risk to sudo such stuff. It could modify (or upload) any files on your system. And indeed, we’ve seen some build scripts try to modify /usr even when the prefix was specified as something else entirely.

To execute the program with `sudo` use the `-E` option or provide the full PATH to your program.

It is not recommended to add the homebrew binary path to your root shell configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Each user has a set of directories (`$PATH`) used to look for applications.

Your user settings includes copa's path, so copa works without sudo.

The use of `sudo` introduces a different environment. copa's path is not in that environment, so copa cannot be found.

As copa is installed locally within your /home directory instead of globally for all users on the system, `sudo` should not be required under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: could you please tell how to install copa globally?

Comment: Installing copa globally is explained in the copa documentation: https://project-copacetic.github.io/copacetic/website/installation

Comment: I have installed ` Homebrew` for my `ubuntu-22-04` machine and when I am running `brew install copa`, it's not installing globally

Comment: Read the instructions again. That's only for local (single-user) installation.